# operator [][] matrix c++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-keyword

Im trying to create an operator that gives me the value for the position i,j of a certain matrix and another one that "fills" the matrix in the given positions, ive tried to put the operator that you can see in the header but it isnt working, the problem might be somewhere else but i think this it the main issue:

````
    int main()
    {
        matriz a(3,3);
        matrizQuad b(3);
    
        for(size_t i=0;i<3;++i)
            for(size_t j=0;j<3;++j){
                a[i][j]=1;
                b[i][j]=2;
            }
        matriz c=a+b;
        cout << "a+b:\n" << c << "\n";
        cout << "traco: " << b.traco() << "\n";
    
        return 0;
    } ``` 
    
    Header:
    
    #ifndef MATRIZES_H
    #define MATRIZES_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <ostream>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    
    typedef vector<vector<double>> array;
    
    class matriz
    {
    protected:
        int iLargura, iComprimento;
        array m;
    public:
        matriz(int L, int C): iLargura (L), iComprimento (C)
        {
            array m(L);
            for (int i = 0; i<L;i++)
                m[i].resize(C);
        };
    
        int nL() const {return iLargura;}
        int nC() const {return iComprimento;}
    
        vector<double>& operator[] (int i) {return  m[i];}
        const vector<double>& operator[] (int i) const {return  m[i];}
    
    };
    
    class matrizQuad: public matriz
    {
    public:
        matrizQuad (int T): matriz(T,T) {}
        double traco();
    };
    
    matriz operator+(const matriz& m1, const matriz& m2);
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const matriz& m1);
    
    
    #endif // MATRIZES_H
    
    Body: 
    
    #include "matriz.h"
    
    
    double matrizQuad::traco()
    {
        double dSoma = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i<iLargura; i++)
            for (int j = 0;i<iLargura; i++)
                if (i==j)
                    dSoma = dSoma + m[i][j];
        return dSoma;
    }
    
    matriz operator+(const matriz& m1, const matriz& m2)
    {
        int C1 = m1.nC();
        int L1 = m1.nL();
        matriz m(C1,L1);
    
        for (int i = 0;i<C1; i++)
            for (int j = 0;i<L1; i++)
                m[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        return m;
    }
    
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const matriz& m1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< m1.nL();i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<m1.nC();j++)
                output << m1[i][j] << " ";
            output << "\n";
        }
    
        return output;
    }
````

Comment: what is the meaning of "isn't working" ?

Comment: neither does the matrix  appear on the screen nor is it filling the positions,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the observations, don't put relevant info into comments. Also, reduce your problem to a [mcve].

Comment: Please note that `using namespace std;` followed by `typedef vector<vector<double>> array;` is a really, really [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) idea, given [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) exists and it's nothing like a vector of vectors.

Comment: `operator[]` should take a `std::size_t` but apart from that there is nothing wrong with it. Keep looking somewhere else for the error.

Comment: Note: adding or multiplying matrixes of different dimensions doesn't work. The dimensions should really by part of the type so ill-formed operations will fail to compile.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Read [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the array resize as 463035818_is_not_a_number suggested gives you a somewhat working matrix.

```
    matriz(int L, int C): iLargura (L), iComprimento (C)
    {
        m.resize(L);
        for (int i = 0; i<L;i++)
            m[i].resize(C);
    };
```

If you also print the matrixes a and b you get:

```
a:
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 1 

b:
2 2 2 
2 2 2 
2 2 2 

a+b:
3 0 0 
3 0 0 
3 0 0
```

So setting and printing matrixes works just fine. The error is in the `operator +`:

```
matriz operator+(const matriz& m1, const matriz& m2)
{
    int C1 = m1.nC();
    int L1 = m1.nL();
    matriz m(C1,L1);

    for (int i = 0;i<C1; i++)
        for (int j = 0;i<L1; i++)
            m[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
    return m;
}
```

specifically:

```
        for (int j = 0;i<L1; i++)
```

I guess you copy&pasted the previous loop for `i` and forgot to rename all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has a member

```
array m;
```

This nested vector is never resized. It has size `0`.

In the constructor you declare a nested vector of same name

```
array m(L);
```

Whose inner vectors you resize in the constructor. Any subsequent access to the members inner vectors elements is out of bounds.

Do not declare another nested vector of same name in the constructor, but instead resize the member.

Note that `array` is rather misleading for a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. Moreover a nested vector is not an efficient 2d data structure. Anyhow, it is also not clear what your `matriz` does that you cannot already get from the `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

Comment: so where should I resize the matrix? and should i delete the array m; in the protected members?

Comment: @JoãoRoque if you want to resize the member do not declare a new vector of same name, `array m(L);` -> `m.resize(L);`

Comment: ok that makes sense, but still the program isnt filling the positions of the matrix, do you have any ideia why?